# Classic Asp session value lost in Response.Redirect

Tags: session, asp-classic, vbscript

I have a **"login.asp"** page where I am setting a session variable.

```
Session("username") = username
```

and accessing the value like :

```
Dim username 
username = Session("username")
response.write(username )
```

I am also using this value in the same page using "response.write" (i.e. in vbscript). After that, I am redirecting the user to **"user.asp"**. In this page, when I try to access the session value, it returns null. How can I get the session value in the redirected page?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How are you accessing the session value in your user.asp page? Add the code to your question.

Comment: Thank you Nicholas.I have modified the question.Added 
  Dim username 
  username = Session("username")
  response.write(username )

Comment: Which browsers are your testing with?  Have you disabled session cookies on the browser?  What does your redirect code look like? User.asp is in the application? Have you used fiddler to observe the conversation between browser and server?  If so is a ASPSESSION cookie being sent to user.asp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code below works:

Setting the username Session Variable

login.asp

```
<%
Dim username  
username = "auser"

Session("username") = username 
response.redirect("user.asp") 
%>
```

Getting the username Session Variable

user.asp

```
<%
Dim username  
username = Session("username") 

response.write("username=" + username ) 
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting it but getting it in your example. Try in your login

```
Session("username") = username
```

and

```
username = Session("username")
```

in your user.asp

I myself i have a routine for that, but you have to use NTLM to let it work
I import it in all my pages where i need it with

```
<!--#include file="routines.asp"-->
```

And in routines.asp i have

```
Function getUser()
  getUser = uCase(Request.ServerVariables("AUTH_USER"))
End Function
```

Comment: Sorry Peter.Actually I am setting the session,but missed to place in the question during edit.

Comment: if i were you i would consider my routine. like that the user can get to any page without being redirected and still have the proper variable, since i use this all this kind of hastle is history

Comment: NTLM requires all users to be known by the domain and under classic ASP would require all ASP script to run as these users.  This approach is only viable in an intranet environment but the question does not indicate that an intranet is being implemented.